# wordpress custom post type pagination -- previous posts link showing when no previous posts exist

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Lots of questions about custom post types and pagination, but as far as I can find, no-one else with this problem:

- Post type created -- check
- new query for custom archive page  -- check
- page one totally loads correctly -- check
- page two shows posts it should -- check.  BUT: it also still has the **previous posts** link.
- which point to page three, even though there are no posts to display

The problem:  post navigation still shows on page two, allowing for a click to page 3 (4, 5, 6 etc) -- where there are no posts. No 404, just a blank page, as though the loop is still looping through an infinite sea of nothingness.

Code:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'portfolio',
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'paged'=>$paged
) ); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<article >
/*stuff in here */
 </article>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div id="post-navigation">
<div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link(__( 'Previous Projects' )) ?></div>
<div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link(__( 'Next Projects' )) ?></div>
</div><!-- #post-navigation -->
```

Other info:  I'm displaying this with archive-portfolio.php -- no blank page to muddy up permalinks.

On page 1, there's no option for next post -- so that half seems to be working, but previous just lets me go back in time forever, where there are no posts to display.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok -- asked too soon.  Here's the code that fixes the problem.  If anyone can tell me why, that would be awesome. Otherwise it's all cargo cult....

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>


<?php query_posts('post_type=portfolio&posts_per_page=10&caller_get_posts=1&paged='. $paged ); ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<article  >

/*stuff in here */

</article>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div id="post-navigation">
<div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link(__( 'Previous Projects' )) ?></div>
<div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link(__( 'Next Projects' )) ?></div>
</div><!-- #post-navigation -->
<?php else : endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can refer [from here on wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links):

--

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I did check that out -- really just unclear about why the original code didn't work, and the second code I tried did.

Comment: It may be your syntax error or something going wrong with wp implementation.